# How to detect "{" or "}" in .format

Tags: python

I'm not able to detect the characters of `'{'` or `'}'`.

This line:

```
if char == "{" or char == "}":
```

doesn't detect `'{'` or '`}'` and I can't figure it out.

```
not_one_space = False

text_example = "{}          Welcome to...\n     {}Minecraft{} but it's                 
text".format(text_color_green, text_color_blue, text_color_green)
for char in text_example:
  sys.stdout.write(char)
  sys.stdout.flush()
  if char != " ":
    if char == ".":
      time.sleep(.4)
    if char == "{" or char == "}":
      ()
    else:
      time.sleep(.1)
      not_one_space = True
  elif not_one_space == True:
    time.sleep(.1)
    not_one_space = False
```

Actual Results: It doesn't detect it and the code continues to else meaning that it sleeps for `.1` seconds which I don't want.

Expected: It detects both `'{'` and `'}'` and runs that if statement.

Comment: Try `print(repr(text_example))` and see if it contains any braces. (If `text_color_…` don’t, it won’t. `.format()` replaces the `{}`s with the arguments you pass it. If you were trying to do something with those, well… you’ll have to find a different way. I suggest multiple loops.)

Comment: If you want to replace the arguments of `format`, and keep the curly braces, look at @ShadowRanger 's answer

Comment: Well that does work but then it prints curly brackets too,  and I don't want that

Comment: I actually found a way to get rid of the curly brackets but then it still has the format

Answer (score 2):

Calling `.format` on the format string *replaced* all the curly braces. Each set was replaced with the string version of one of the arguments to `format`; if they didn't contain braces, then there aren't any left.

If you want to insert those values, but leave them surrounded by braces, you'll need to add two extra sets of braces around each use, e.g.:

```
text_example = "{{{}}}          Welcome to...\n     {{{}}}Minecraft{{{}}} but it's text".format(text_color_green, text_color_blue, text_color_green)
```

Answer (score 1):

When  you define `text_example` you immediately execute its `format` method. That method *removes* the braces and *replaces* them with the values of the variables mentioned as parameters in the method.

So of course the braces are gone later in the code.

The only way braces could be in `text_example` is if one of the parameter values in the `format` method has braces in it. You do not show the values of those parameter values, but given their names that is very unlikely.

---

Here is code that does what you seem to want. I tried to keep your code structure as much as possible, even though I would prefer a different structure. Here are some of my changes:

1. I added the needed `import` statements.
2. I added definitions for your `text_color_green` and `text_color_blue` variables. I don't know what you wanted so I put values suitable for testing.
3. I removed the `format` method from your string definition so it keeps the `{}` markers.
4. I added a list that contains the values you want to use to replace the `{}` markers. These last two are the equivalent of what you did but does not remove the markers.
5. I added two checks on the "character" from your string before it is printed. I ignore it for `}` so it isn't printed and I print one of the format values for `{`. It therefore may not be a character so it would be best to change the variable name to something other than `char`--I'll leave that to you.
6. I changed your test for `{` or `}` to just the former, since the latter causes this part of the code to be skipped.
7. I changed your `()` line to `pass` to make its purpose more clear.

The result seems correct. Test it yourself and change the color codes.

```
import sys
import time 

text_color_green, text_color_blue = "(green)", "(blue)"
not_one_space = False

text_format = "{}          Welcome to...\n     {}Minecraft{} but it's text."
text_params = [text_color_green, text_color_blue, text_color_green]
for char in text_format:
    if char == "}":
        continue
    if char == "{":
        char = text_params.pop(0)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if char != " ":
        if char == ".":
            time.sleep(.4)
        elif char == "{":
            pass
        else:
            time.sleep(.1)
            not_one_space = True
    elif not_one_space == True:
        time.sleep(.1)
        not_one_space = False
```

Comment: So can you think of any way that I can have it detect the format? Thanks!

Comment: @Minxx73Minxx73: What do you mean by "detect the format"?

Comment: To detect the format you have to examine the string before you format it. Once you call `format` the formatting placeholders are gone and you cannot know what they were.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I'm trying to get the curly brackets or "format" recognized so I can avoid a time.sleep to occur.

Comment: @Minxx73Minxx73: It is still not clear. Exactly *when* do you want to avoid the `time.sleep`? Do you mean that you want the regular characters to be printed slowly but the characters that replaced the brackets to print quickly? You could keep the string *without* the format method applied. Then scan through the unformatted string. When you reach braces in the unformatted, quickly print he related parameter string then keep scanning through the unformatted string. If that is what you mean, is this algorithm clear?

Comment: Yes, I only want the text to be have `time.sleep` while everything else has no `time.sleep`          EDIT: If I delete the format then my text won't change color which is what I added the format for in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @RoryDaulton That was what I needed.

Comment: @Minxx73Minxx73: You are welcome! On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer, if you have enough reputation to do so. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.